# does boto3 have a way to get resource limits from a region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, python

Right now I am looking for ec2 instances type limits for a given region.  I would like to put in place an audit script that tracks our usage vs our limits for a given set of things.  Also open to other tools that work well with Python

thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure all classes in boto3 which have limits have a decribe-account-limits method... Or just use boto3 for a raw request on this (see aws API documentation)

Comment: For exemple https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/autoscaling.html#AutoScaling.Client.describe_account_limits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure it does, otherwise it wouldn't be the module in use in:

```
https://awslimitchecker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
```

From their setup.py installation script:

```
requires = [
    'boto3>=1.4.6',
    'botocore>=1.6.0',
    'termcolor>=1.1.0',
    'python-dateutil>=2.4.2',
    'versionfinder>=0.1.1',
    'pytz'
]
```

Thing is, maybe what you're trying to build is already built in some way or another. Try searching for libraries that has more or less the description of the tool you're trying to build, before starting.

Happy coding!

Comment: If you provide a code snippet I’ll award the bounty, a one-liner isn’t enough I’m afraid!